# Android target API - Can't create project with activity

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I've a problem while creating a project.

When I want to create a simple project with blank activity, I can't proceed the steps and I receive this message:

> This template requires a build target API version of at least 14, and the current is 7

Comment: Are you selecting some navigation template during setup?

Comment: Change in `manifest.xml` with this: `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />` **OR** set Minimum sdk version to `API 14`, when you creating the project.

Comment: @Minas No, there isn't any navigation

Comment: @T-Rush But you know, I want to create my project with API 7 in order to some reasons.

Comment: Then you must be adding some code/functionality that previous `API`s not supports. Let me know if I'm wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most Templates use Features like the ActionBar or Fragments.

If you want to create an app from a template that is backwards compatible.

This is how you can create a compatible template using the wizard:

> 1. Right click your package explorer > New > Android Application
> 2. Enter your details, and make sure to select "none" as theme
> 3. Pick the highest possible Minimum SDK that fits your needs
> 4. When you arrive at the "Create Activity" Screen, select "Blank Activity"
> 5. Finish.

If you would like more features to start with, you can also pick a sample from the SDK (like ActionBarCompat) and use that as a template for your app.

Answer (score 1):

**This did it for me:**

In **Eclipse**, click on the **project** menu, and then click on **properties**, the project properties interface will load. In the "Android Properties" ensure you check the  check box of the build target with the higher API number (in this case API 14) in the error you are getting.